# Javascript | Set all values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Code**

```
var cool = new Array(3);
cool[setAll] = 42; //cool[setAll] is just a pseudo selector..
alert(cool);
```

**Result**

A alert message:

```
42,42,42
```

How do I change/set all values of an array to a specific value?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's no built-in way, you'll have to loop over all of them:

```
function setAll(a, v) {
    var i, n = a.length;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = v;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/xG88A/

If you *really* want, do this:

```
Array.prototype.setAll = function(v) {
    var i, n = this.length;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        this[i] = v;
    }
};
```

and then you could actually do `cool.setAll(42)` (see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ee3hb/).

Some people frown upon extending the prototype of built-in types, though.

**EDIT** ES5 introduced a way to safely extend both `Object.prototype` and `Array.prototype` without breaking `for ... in ...` enumeration:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'setAll', {
    value: function(v) {
        ...
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2** In ES6 draft there's also now `Array.prototype.fill`, usage `cool.fill(42)`

Comment: I feel obliged to add a caveat here: extending native objects (in this case `Array`) is considered bad practice by most.

Comment: @Steve which is exactly what I say in the last line.  However ES5 provides a safe way to do it using `Object.createProperty(Array.prototype, 'setAll', ...)`

Comment: Whoops my bad. TLDR is getting shorter and shorter these days :)

Comment: thanks for the fill tip. Fill is a lot of fun. I ended up using clones of manually created arrays (`var1 = [...ArrayOfTrue]; var2 = [...ArrayOfFalse]` is quicker in my case then `var1.fill(true)` but it'll be usefull down the line I'm sure.

Answer (score 46):

The ES6 approach is very clean. So first you initialize an array of x length, and then call the `fill` method on it.

```
let arr = new Array(3).fill(9)
```

this will create an array with 3 elements like:

```
[9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Sadly there is very little browser support for the `.fill()` method as of 2016. However, I found this very useful for use with TypeScript.

Comment: @MarcoDelValle it's not a problem with a polyfill

Comment: @Marquizzo There should be better support here in 2019

Comment: Yes, it's improved substantially in the last 3 years. It looks like as of today, [only IE does not support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: This should be the best answer in 2019

Answer (score 28):

`map` is the most logical solution for this problem.

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3];
xs = xs.map(x => 42);
xs // -> [42, 42, 42]
```

However, if there is a chance that the array is sparse, you'll need to use `for` or, even better, `for .. of`.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: poor answer - not only is this is a misuse of `Array.prototype.map` (you should use `forEach` to iterate over an array, and `.map` only if you wish to _`return`_ a new array based on it) but also requires that the array _already have values in it_.  Both `.map` and `.forEach` will ignore array elements that have undefined keys.

Comment: @Alnitak See the second code example for point #1, and don't see why point #2 makes this a poor answer. Does this approach "Set all values of an array"? Yes.

Comment: @mustafa.0x no, it _doesn't_ "set all values of an array".  JS arrays can be sparse, i.e. there can be elements between `0` and `length - 1` that have no defined value.   `.map` will ignore those elements, leaving the array unfilled.  The second `.map` version fails the OP requirement in that it returns a _new_ array, and does not mutate the original.

Comment: @Alnitak I can change the second example to `xs = xs.map()` if that's important to you =)

Comment: No, my point is that `.map` is _entirely_ the wrong tool for the job not just because of its array return semantics but also because of the sparse element skipping.

Comment: @Alnitak I would argue it depends on the job; for many use cases `.map` is a fine solution, and most JS devs are aware of this behavior. Either way, I can add a disclaimer noting that `.map` and similar methods skip over sparse elements, so that if that's the dev's use case, they know to use another solution.

Comment: I agree that `.map` is a very good solution to many problems, I often highly recommend it myself.  But not for this.

Answer (score 4):

It's 2019 and you should be using this:

`let arr = [...Array(20)].fill(10)`

So basically `20` is the `length` or a new instantiated `Array`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop and set each one in turn.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use this perfect approach:

```
let arr = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(() => 0);
// [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This code will create array and fill it with zeroes.
Or just:

```
let arr = new Array(5).fill(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are Ok, but a while loop seems more appropriate:

```
function setAll(array, value) {
  var i = array.length;
  while (i--) {
    array[i] = value;
  }
}
```

A more creative version:

```
function replaceAll(array, value) {
  var re = new RegExp(value, 'g');
  return new Array(++array.length).toString().replace(/,/g, value).match(re);
}
```

May not work everywhere though. :-)

Comment: good choice for the reverse array loop, we need more of those in js land

Answer (score 0):

Found this while working with Epicycles - clearly works - where 'p' is invisible to my eyes.

```js
/** Convert a set of picture points to a set of Cartesian coordinates */
function toCartesian(points, scale) {
  const x_max = Math.max(...points.map(p=>p[0])),
  y_max = Math.max(...points.map(p=>p[1])),
  x_min = Math.min(...points.map(p=>p[0])),
  y_min = Math.min(...points.map(p=>p[1])),
  signed_x_max = Math.floor((x_max - x_min + 1) / 2),
  signed_y_max = Math.floor((y_max - y_min + 1) / 2);

  return points.map(p=>
  [ -scale * (signed_x_max - p[0] + x_min),
  scale * (signed_y_max - p[1] + y_min) ] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [empty statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty).

```js
const arr = [1, 2 ,3];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; arr[i++] = 42);
console.log(arr);
```