# How do I fill an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to overwrite all values in it (that are all numbers) with a 0. So the array already exists.

I can do this with a for loop. However, is there a fill() call of some kind like the Java Arrays.fill()?

Comment: I think a `for` loop is your only option.

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802762/javascript-set-all-values-of-an-array

Comment: You can prototype your own method and then call it directly on the array

Comment: Just an FYI, with Harmony (ECMAScript 6), there will be a [fill method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).  I know, doesn't help out now.

Comment: @AbuSulaiman - Thank you. For whatever reason when I did a search on this, I did not find that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple for-loop is all you need. There's no fill-function in JavaScript.

```
var length = arr.length,
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  arr[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map for this.

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr = arr.map(function() {return 0});
//arr = [0, 0, 0]
```

The performance may be worse than a plain for loop.